# Which copy data more faster in Java while using FileChannel.transferFrom and while()?

Tags: java, nio

The following Java code in two ways to copy files which more efficient? Want to be able to explain why, thank you.
By the way, I've tested the same file which size is about 300 megabytes. The speed of the first method as fast as the second one. But after tested more times, the result is differently. 
One of my test result as below:

- NO.1: Using transferFrom took 3396ms
- NO.1: Using while took 3334ms
- NO.2: Using transferFrom took 4239ms
- NO.2: Using while took 3225ms
- NO.3: Using transferFrom took 3906ms
- NO.3: Using while took 4153ms
- NO.4: Using transferFrom took 3100ms
- NO.4: Using while took 3174ms
- NO.5: Using transferFrom took 3156ms
- NO.5: Using while took 3180ms

Code:

```
public void copyData(String inPath, String outPath1, String outPath2) {
    FileChannel inChannel = null;
    FileChannel outChannel = null;
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    File out1File = null;
    File out2File = null;
    int bufferLen = 20480 * 2 * 1024;
    long runTime;
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferLen);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(new File(inPath));
            out1File = new File(outPath1);
            fout = new FileOutputStream(out1File);
            inChannel = fin.getChannel();
            outChannel = fout.getChannel();
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            outChannel.transferFrom(inChannel, 0, inChannel.size());
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - runTime;
            System.out.println("NO." + (i + 1) + ": "
                    + "Using transferFrom took " + runTime + "ms");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != fin) {
                try {
                    fin.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (null != fout) {
                try {
                    fout.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (null != inChannel) {
                try {
                    inChannel.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (null != outChannel) {
                try {
                    outChannel.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            out1File.deleteOnExit();
        }
        /**********************************************************/
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(new File(inPath));
            out2File = new File(outPath2);
            fout = new FileOutputStream(out2File);
            inChannel = fin.getChannel();
            outChannel = fout.getChannel();
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) {
                int ret = inChannel.read(bb);
                if (ret == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                bb.flip();
                outChannel.write(bb);
                bb.clear();
            }
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - runTime;
            System.out.println("NO." + (i + 1) + ": " + "Using while took "
                    + runTime + "ms");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != fin) {
                try {
                    fin.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (null != fout) {
                try {
                    fout.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (null != inChannel) {
                try {
                    inChannel.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (null != outChannel) {
                try {
                    outChannel.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            out2File.deleteOnExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `transferTo()` and `transferFrom()` aren't guaranteed to perform the entire requested transfer in one operation. You have to loop.

Comment: Measuring I/O speed is always tricky as it lots of dependencies to the current state of the operating system, e.g. cache state. But you’re benchmark has additional flaws, e.g. you don’t `flush` nor `close` within the measured code so there’s no guaranty that the data are really written by the underlying system. And you should learn about `System.nanoTime` and why it’s preferable when measuring elapsed time.

Comment: @EJP I searched the docs.. no where its mentioned "not guaranteed to perform", if you have some references do provide the links. I am thinking the internal algorithm is taking care of it.

Comment: [`FileChannel.transferFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long)): “An invocation of this method may or may not transfer all of the requested bytes”

Comment: The documentation of transferFrom and transferTo could be a lot clearer, but careful reading of those docs reveals that the methods are in fact guaranteed to do a full transfer in one call, as long as the other Channel is not configured to be non-blocking.  Which is good, since there would be no way to know when to break out of a transferFrom loop except to read until one gets a ClosedChannelException.

Comment: @user3020494 (1) The words "an attempt is made". (2) The words "an invocation of this method may or may not transfer all of the requested bytes". (3) The fact that it doesn't state that it *is* 'guaranteed to perform the entire requested transfer'. (4) The fact that it returns a count of the bytes actually transferred. How much evidence do you need exactly?

Comment: @VGR (1) Careful reading of those documentations reveals nothing of the sort. See above. (2) Reading until a `ClosedChannelException` occurs isn't a solution: who would close the channel? (3) The solution would be to keep track of the current and total bytes to b be transferred and stop when they're the same. It's curious that these methods don't return -1 at EOS, but there it is.

Comment: As I read it, the sentence which immediately follows "may or may not transfer all of the requested bytes" goes on to explain the precise circumstances under which the method will not transfer all of the requested bytes.  If that is not the case, perhaps one of us should submit a bug to the Java Bug Database about the methods' need to return -1.

Comment: @VGR The final sentence in the paragraph describes two conditions under which the method *must* transfer fewer than the requested number of bytes, and it is difficult to see how else the channel could possibly behave. However the additional wording "whether or not it does so depends upon the natures and states of the channels" clearly permits implementations to do so for any other reason.